# Set System Environment variable before Qt application start

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have developed one sample Qt application. My application runs only when we execute below command in terminal first.

```
export QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
```

If we don't export above variable and start application ( "./test") then it open the window but it has some paint rendering issue.

Can anyone suggest, how can we set this variable from application itself rather then externally set from terminal ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe starting application from a shell script will help? Script will set the environment and start the executable.

Comment: By providing script with your app that do `QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 path/to/real/app $@` ?

Comment: Script will be the solution but i want to do it with application if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using `qputenv()` to add it before you create the `QApplication` in `main()`. Some of the `ENV vars` must be set before Qt begins loading due to them being used in global state, I'm not sure if the `X11` ones will work with `qputenv()` but that's the best way to introduce them in the codebase. [QtGlobal::qputenv documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qputenv).